# Парсинг youtube ссылки

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь распарсить youtube ссылку на видео, для вставки его на сайт.

Код следующий:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_query);
echo '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $parsed_query['v'] . '" type="text/html" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
```

Я использую это на WordPress. Проблема оказалась в том, что если в $url забита ссылка, тогда все красиво. Но если я переменной $url присваиваю значение динамически из админки, то я получаю вывод `http://www.youtube.com/embed/` без численного кода видео.

Comment: что такое «значение custom field»? добавьте, пожалуйста, расшифровку непосредственно в вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin отредактировал пост.

Comment: А Вы пробовали в админке ввести не полный адрес, а только код видео. Т.е. в Вашем случае  `jNQXAC9IVRw`? Может он окажется умным и добавит это в embed?

Comment: @cyadvert если просто вводить код видео, то это конечно все намного упрощает. Но не для пользователя;) Гораздо удобнее просто скопировать ссылку из строки адреса и вставить в соотвествуюшее место в админке. Та и мне не надо чтобы WP автоматически вставлял в embed.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот эти регулярки

```
if ( preg_match( "/(http|https):\/\/(www.youtube|youtube|youtu)\.(be|com)\/([^<\s]*)/", $url, $match ) ) {
  if ( preg_match( '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id ) ) {
      $values = $id[1];
  } else if ( preg_match( '/youtube\.com\/embed\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id ) ) {
     $values = $id[1];
  } else if ( preg_match( '/youtube\.com\/v\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id ) ) {
    $values = $id[1];
  } else if ( preg_match( '/youtu\.be\/([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id ) ) {
    $values = $id[1];
  } else if ( preg_match( '/youtube\.com\/verify_age\?next_url=\/watch%3Fv%3D([^\&\?\/]+)/', $url, $id ) ) {
    $values = $id[1]; 
  }
}
```